# Getting JSON array elements values

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to show data received from a remote JSON source on a HTML table.

This is part of the script I am using now

```
var loadData = function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"http://......"
                }).done(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    var users = JSON.parse(data);
                    for(var i in users){
                        $("#content").append("<td>"+users[ i ]+"</td>");
                    }
                });
```

The console shows following output:

```
{"data":[["1","PMI-M-072"]]}
```

On the first td tag appear 1,PMI-M-072 as value.
But I need to show each array element on a td tag. 
How can I get each element value?

Comment: That code looks like you are using jQuery. I suggest adding this as a tag to your question.

Comment: @contradictioned, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to do:

```
var users = JSON.parse(data)["data"];
```

instead of:

```
var users = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: and then how do I get each element value?

Comment: If an element is always in the form `["1","PMI-M-072"]`, and "PMI-M-072" is the value you're looking for, do `users[i][1]`